# Dataframe group by with frequency count

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am having a hard time manipulating the below dataframe.

[image: Screenshot of dataframe]

I would like to count the frequency of each `LIBELLE` within a same `CLI_ID` and add it into a new column. In red is an example of what the dataframe should look like.

For `CLI_ID` `1490281`, he bought twice `GD JDM4 PAMPLEMOUSSE FL 200ML` so I set `QTY` to `2` for each row with `LIBELLE` of `GD JDM4 PAMPLEMOUSSE FL 200ML`.

`groupby(['CLI_ID','LIBELLE'])...` does not seem to be the solution.

Comment: `df['QTY'] = df.groupby(['LIBELLE', 'CLI_ID'])['LIBELLE'].transform('size')` ...?

Answer (score 0):

```py
new_df = df[['LIBELLE', 'CLI_ID']].groupby('LIBELLE').count()
final_df = df.merge(new_df, left_on='LIBELLE', right_index=True)
```

Comment: Kindly add a line or two to explain what you are doing. This will help the readers to understand the answer more clearly. Note: This post was flagged as a low-quality post.